# Change what is rendered in structural directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

So, I am creating a structural directive similar to NgIf and I have the following

```
this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
```

Which makes perfect sense for what I need but there is a requirement to dynamically show an error if condition is a particular value.

So in sudo code it would be something like,

if everything is fine - show the original template, if the bound value is 42 then show the error component instead of the original one.

Is this possible?

I was hoping I could do something like

```
this.viewContainer.createEmbeededView(new TemplateRef<ErrorComponent());
```

Any help would be great as I have been banging my head against the wall for ages on this!

cheers.

Comment: I see a typo in there (missing ```>``` after ErrorComponent and createEmbedded is mispelled) ,  it should be : ```this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(new TemplateRef<ErrorComponent>());  ```

Comment: Thanks I am 100% sure that code would never work even I had used it :)

Comment: @Steoates create 2 directive, one that shows `ErrorComponent` in case `errorCondition` and another that show whatever when `normalCondition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can create a `TemplateRef` using `new`.

Just add an additional error template in your view and pass a reference to this error template to `createEmbeddedView` instead in case of an error.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on this mate? I think I get what your saying but just want to me sure!

Comment: Can you please provide more details (more code) that demonstrates what you try to accomplish? Then it's easier to build a concrete example.